# Getting errors when sending ETH to a contract on testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, cpp-ethereum

I am trying to send ETH to a contract I have just created and I am getting errors

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;
contract Owned {
    modifier only_owner {
        if (msg.sender != owner) return; _;
    }

    event NewOwner(address indexed old, address indexed current);

    function setOwner(address _new) only_owner { NewOwner(owner, _new); owner = _new; }

    address public owner = msg.sender;
}
```

[image]

Anyone have any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think any function that accepts Ether should be set as "payable"

Read more here: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html

Comment: plus if you don't provide any functions for dealing with the Ether, it will just be stuck there forever

Comment: Im okay with it being stuck there.. i just wanted to test if i can change the owner by sending some ether to it